# Android : getting NullPointerException for ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)

Tags: android, imageview

I am getting Null Pointer Exception for ImageView imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image). I have custome layout declared in **R.layout.screen3** with custome list declared in **R.layout.custom_row_screen3**. Each row has few tasks and depending on their status an image is shown to right of each row.

Please guide me in getting this resolved as I am new to android.

here is my code below :::

```
public class screen3 extends ListActivity{
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
...
...
...
TextView tv;
ImageView imag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen3);   
    System.out.println("Screen3");
    ...
    ...
    ...
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.custom_row_screen3,
            new String[] { "tname","schedule", "note", "time"}, new int[] { R.id.text1Screen3task,
                    R.id.text2Screen3task, R.id.text3Screen3task, R.id.text4Screen3task});
    populateList();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void populateList() {
    for(int i = 0; i <numberOfTasks; i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h = tasks.get(i);
            ...
            ...     
        hm.put("tname", h.get("taskName"));
        hm.put("schedule", h.get("STime")+" - "+h.get("ETime"));

        if(h.get("taskStatus").trim().equals("1")){

            imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);//   <<---- NULL RETURNED
            imag.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
            ...
            ...
        }
        else{
            imag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);//  <<---- NULL RETURNED
            imag.setImageResource(R.drawable.not);
            ...
            ...
        }
        list.add(hm);
    }
    ...
    ... 
}
```

**screen3 xml**

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
```

**custom_row_screen3 xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1Screen3task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="21sp" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2Screen3task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="clip_horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text3Screen3task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="clip_horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text4Screen3task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="16sp" android:gravity="clip_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="51dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
    />
```

Thanks
Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: Are you sure your screen3 layout have an ImageView naming as image? If yes can you post your screen3.xml codes?

Comment: 05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scandihealth/com.scandihealth.screen3}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

Comment: 05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at com.scandihealth.screen3.populate(screen3.java:141)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at com.scandihealth.screen3.onCreate(screen3.java:49)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 15:45:18.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(488):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: @pankaj : Screen3 xml is not having imageView
it is in custom_row. I am populating a custom list in screen3 and custom row has imageView.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi : put ur imageview inside linearlayout.

Comment: Do you use multiple layout resource? e.g. - layout/main.xml
- layout-land/main.xml Have you specified theirs id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you
You all all pointed me in right direction that my imageview is not pointing to my adapter
I followed the steps as in http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/
and it was working!!!
just needed to put my image in hashmap... I was banging my head to the wall!!!

Answer (score 1):

In short: You should write a ListAdapter which draws the views in the list. You seem to use `findViewById()` on the wrong view/context (on the screen3 xml layout). An example containing a ListAdapter is [available at the android developer site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html).

The `getView()` method should basically look something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    h = tasks.get(i);
    if(h.get("taskStatus").trim().equals("1")){
        imag = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imag.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
    } else { 
        // ...
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail. I am new to android :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't specified android:id="@+id/image" in the imageview inside your layout

Edit: I think the problem is you are using findViewById before the ListView in your ListActivity contains your custom_row which is who has the ImageView.

Try doing setListAdapter before populateList()

Comment: it is there in R.layout.custom_row_screen3 as 
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="51dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
  />

Comment: Post the code of screen3 layout if you can.
Maybe you're using the findViewById method of the wrong view and it haven't the image inside.

Comment: I can't post it right now... just joined this forum so there is 8 hr restriction... will try to post in parts

Answer (score 0):

check whether the resource which your laoding is available in your res folder or not.

Answer (score 0):

populateList() runs before the ListView is rendered to the screen, so the custom_row_screen3 doesn't exist in the Activity.

You could subclass SimpleAdapter and override getView() or [setViewImage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewImage%28android.widget.ImageView,%20int%29), but I often find it simpler to anonymously implement a [SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html) and assign it with [SimpleAdapter#setViewBinder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder%29).

In the ViewBinder, return false if the View that's passed in isn't an ImageView. If it is, you can use the map of data (passed in as an Object) to check the value of the "taskStatus" key.

Make sure to do this *before* calling setListAdapter().

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder () {
  @Override
  boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
    if (!(view instanceof ImageView)) return false;

    String taskStatus = ((Map<String, String>) data).get("taskStatus").trim();
    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(taskStatus.equals("1") ? R.drawable.done :
                                                               R.drawable.not);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but its total confusion for me right now!!! I am a novice in android and not used Binders and all.

Comment: not working 
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(.....);
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder () { @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
@Override 
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) 
{ if (!(view instanceof ImageView)) return false; 
String ts = ((HashMap<String, String>) data).get("taskStatus").trim(); ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(ts.equals("1") ? R.drawable.done :R.drawable.not); return true; } }); populateList(); setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @Abhinav: by "not working", do you mean nothing is showing up, that an exception is thrown or that it doesn't compile? Also, try calling populateList() before creating SimpleAdapter